# Create custom attribute for specifi product

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, custom-attributes, setup-script, magento-setup

i'm tring to create a custom attribute only for a specific product.
Into apply_to field i have setted a list "configurable, grouped" , a array('configurable', 'grouped') or single type, but doesn't work fine

what is the problem?

```
    <?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();


$this->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'project_test3', array(
'type'              => 'text',  
'input'             => 'text',
'label'             => 'Project TEST3',
'backend'           => '',
'visible'           => true,
'required'          => false,
'visible_on_front'  => true,
'apply_to'          => 'configurable')); $this->endSetup(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code to create a custom attribute that applies to configurable in Magento 2.

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'attribute_for_config',
        [
            'group' => 'Product Details',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'sort_order' => 50,
            'label' => 'Can be wrapped?',
            'input' => 'boolean',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to'=>'configurable'
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` instead of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup` as your setup resource model.
Because of that, you can't simply add the field `apply_to` directly in the attribute's creation.

If you can, just change (in your `config.xml` file) the class used as your resource in setup to `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup` and you're done:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    ...
    <global>
        <resources>
            <your_setup_name>
              <setup>
                   <module>Your_Module</module>
                   <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
              </setup>
          </your_setup_name>
        </resources>  
    </global>
</config>
```

But if you really need to use `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` as your setup, that's why you're unable to set a value to `apply_to` the way you wanted:

If you look into your installer class (`app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php`) you will se that inside the method `addAttribute()` the data you sent as third parameter (`attr`) is passed to the method `_prepareValues()`:

```php
public function addAttribute($entityTypeId, $code, array $attr)
{
        $entityTypeId = $this->getEntityTypeId($entityTypeId);
        $data = array_merge( 
            array(
                'entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId,
                'attribute_code' => $code
            ),
            $this->_prepareValues($attr) # Here your data is sent to be 'prepared' (including the 'apply_to' field)
         );
         ...
}
```

This "preparation method" applies some validation to values specified in the creation fields (like apply the default value if nothing is set to a field). The problem is: there's no mention of the `apply_to` field in there, so it get lost in the process:

```php
protected function _prepareValues($attr)
    {
        $data = array(
            'backend_model'   => $this->_getValue($attr, 'backend'),
            'backend_type'    => $this->_getValue($attr, 'type', 'varchar'),
            'backend_table'   => $this->_getValue($attr, 'table'),
            'frontend_model'  => $this->_getValue($attr, 'frontend'),
            'frontend_input'  => $this->_getValue($attr, 'input', 'text'),
            'frontend_label'  => $this->_getValue($attr, 'label'),
            'frontend_class'  => $this->_getValue($attr, 'frontend_class'),
            'source_model'    => $this->_getValue($attr, 'source'),
            'is_required'     => $this->_getValue($attr, 'required', 1),
            'is_user_defined' => $this->_getValue($attr, 'user_defined', 0),
            'default_value'   => $this->_getValue($attr, 'default'),
            'is_unique'       => $this->_getValue($attr, 'unique', 0),
            'note'            => $this->_getValue($attr, 'note'),
            'is_global'       => $this->_getValue($attr, 'global', 1)
        );

        return $data;
    }
```

Because now the `$data` returned from this method will be used to actually create the new attribute (whithout the `apply_to`) field.

To fix that, there is two ways (that I can think of):

#### Change the `_prepareValues()` method

I would avoid to use this without further inspection. But you could easily add the `apply_to` to the end of the array inside de `_prepareValues()` method in `app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php`:

```php
protected function _prepareValues($attr)
    {
        $data = array(
            ...
            'apply_to' => $this->_getValue($attr, 'apply_to') # Added `apply_to` field
        );

        return $data;
    }
```

And now you will be able to use the `apply_to` on attribute's creation (like you've done before `"apply_to" => "configurable"`.

#### Safest way

You can create the attribute and, after that, update it's `apply_to` value:

```php
$attributeCode = "project_test3";
$this->startSetup();
# Create new attribute without the "apply_to" field
$this->addAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode, array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Project TEST3',
    'backend' => '',
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
));

# Loading new attribute and setting "apply_to" to "configurable"
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode("catalog_product", $attributeCode);
$attribute->addData(array("apply_to" => "configurable"));
$attribute->save();

$this->endSetup();
```

Using this method you will not need to change any Magento core function.